# Is it possible to remove a column from a composite index on Mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I have a table with a unique index of three columns.
Now I need to remove one column from this index.

What is the best option in this case?

1. Is it possible to remove a column from the index?
2. Delete the existing index and re-create it with the same name?

Comment: No delete the index and create a new one, or add a new index

Comment: A quick way to do it would be use MySQL Workbench and right click what ever you need done.  Download --> https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Comment: Depends - do you have an fk on the first node?

Comment: @P.Salmon No, there is no fk

Comment: @easleyfixed Thanks for the advice. I will use it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    -- Drop the existing index
ALTER TABLE my_table DROP INDEX index_name;

    -- Create a new index without the column you want to remove
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD INDEX index_name (column1, column2);
```

or

```
    -- Modify the index definition without rebuilding the entire table
ALTER TABLE my_table ALGORITHM=INPLACE, DROP INDEX index_name, ADD INDEX index_name (column1, column2);
```

Comment: The first option is the way to go. Step by step is better when dealing with errors.

Comment: Thanks guys. I also considered this option. So there is no index update in MySql

Comment: @Mary - Correct; there is no "index update" command.